# Properly Referencing a ASP Placeholder Programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the below code which is working as intended, however; when a radio button is selected I want the CheckChanged event to add a control to the StatusBar placeholder. How would I reference this control from the event? Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            for (int T = 0; T <= 26; T++)
            {
                Label x = new Label();
                x.ID = T.ToString();
                x.Text = "orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla blandit id felis ac volutpat. Aenean tempor faucibus est, ac feugiat libero egestas sit amet. Aliquam";

                Label y = new Label();
                y.ID = "Title_" + T.ToString();
                y.Text = "Title " + T.ToString();



                RadioButton Radio1 = new RadioButton();
                Radio1.ID = "R_" + T.ToString();
                Radio1.Text = "Yes";
                Radio1.GroupName = "Radio_" + T.ToString();
                Radio1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.CheckedChanged);
                Radio1.AutoPostBack = true;

                RadioButton Radio2 = new RadioButton();
                Radio2.ID = "RX_" + T.ToString();
                Radio2.Text = "No";
                Radio2.GroupName = "Radio_" + T.ToString();
                Radio2.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.CheckedChanged);
                Radio2.AutoPostBack = true;

                PlaceHolder StatusBar = new PlaceHolder();
                StatusBar.ID = "status_" + T.ToString();


                PlaceHolder pcl = new PlaceHolder();
                pcl.ID = "test_" + T.ToString();
                pcl.Controls.Add(y);
                pcl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
                pcl.Controls.Add(x);
                pcl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
                pcl.Controls.Add(Radio1);
                pcl.Controls.Add(Radio2);
                pcl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br><br>"));
                form1.Controls.Add(pcl);
                form1.Controls.Add(StatusBar);
            }
        }


    protected void CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton tRadio = (RadioButton)sender;

        if (tRadio.Text == "Yes")
        {
            Statusbar.Controls.Add(somecontrol);
        }


    }
```

Comment: I can not figure out what is your problem exactly? Also what is somecontrol??

Comment: somecontrol was just a place holder. Let's say that I change that line to   StatusBar.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>">)); . I receive an error stating that "StatusBar does not exist in the current context".

Comment: I was just able to get it working by adding Placeholder StatusBar; outside of the Page_Load event. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: The point of a PlaceHolder control is to keep a spot open in the page so that you can add a control to it conditionally in the code behind. It doesn't really make sense to create PlaceHolders in the code behind and then add them to the form. It makes more sense to put the StatusBar placeholder in the .aspx form rather than creating it dynamically.

Comment: I want to be able to develop an application that is going to loop through say 26 questions coming from a database and have a placeholder at the bottom of each iteration of the loop where data can be added through an event. That's why I am trying to add them programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `FindControl` to find StatusBar Control. Your problem will be solved if you change type of `StatusBar` from `PlaceHolder` To `Panel.

Update: You does not need to use `Panel` Control instead of `PlaceHolder`, But `PlaceHolder` generate  tag, which help you customize appearance of Status bar. I Change your `CheckedChanged` Handler to find StatusBar control and add literal text to it.

Check following code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int T = 0; T <= 26; T++)
        {
            Label x = new Label();
            x.ID = T.ToString();
            x.Text = "orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla blandit id felis ac volutpat. Aenean tempor faucibus est, ac feugiat libero egestas sit amet. Aliquam";

            Label y = new Label();
            y.ID = "Title_" + T.ToString();
            y.Text = "Title " + T.ToString();



            RadioButton Radio1 = new RadioButton();
            Radio1.ID = "R_" + T.ToString();
            Radio1.Text = "Yes";
            Radio1.GroupName = "Radio_" + T.ToString();
            Radio1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.CheckedChanged);
            Radio1.AutoPostBack = true;

            RadioButton Radio2 = new RadioButton();
            Radio2.ID = "RX_" + T.ToString();
            Radio2.Text = "No";
            Radio2.GroupName = "Radio_" + T.ToString();
            Radio2.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.CheckedChanged);
            Radio2.AutoPostBack = true;

            Panel StatusBar = new Panel();

            StatusBar.ID = "status_" + T.ToString();


            PlaceHolder pcl = new PlaceHolder();
            pcl.ID = "test_" + T.ToString();
            pcl.Controls.Add(y);
            pcl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
            pcl.Controls.Add(x);
            pcl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
            pcl.Controls.Add(Radio1);
            pcl.Controls.Add(Radio2);
            pcl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br><br>"));
            form1.Controls.Add(pcl);
            form1.Controls.Add(StatusBar);
        }

        //form1.Controls.Add(new PlaceHolder { ID = "MyStatusBar" });
    }

    protected void CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton tRadio = (RadioButton)sender;
        var T = tRadio.ID.Split('_')[1];

        var statusBarID = "status_" + T;

        var StatusBar = tRadio.Parent.FindControl(statusBarID) as Panel;

        if (tRadio.Text == "Yes")
        {
            StatusBar.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("SampleText"));
        }


    }
```